# Can't select image for site identity logo in Customizer menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I select the image I want, this is the screen I get.

[blank media library menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAV7k.png)

I'm thinking a plugin I have installed is effecting this. Got any ideas?

Comment: maybe disable plugins one by one to see which one cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

How many **plugins** you've got in your installation?

The most common reasons your Media Library has stopped working properly are incompatible plugins and/or themes and improperly set file permissions. Fortunately, they can likely be resolved simply and quickly.

First, I recommend you test out your plugins. Navigate to **Plugins > Installed Plugins** within WordPress. Select the top checkbox next to Plugin (to select all plugins) and choose **Deactivate** from the Bulk Actions drop-down menu. Click Apply, then return to your Media Library.

If it loads, one of your plugins is the issue. Unfortunately, there’s no easy way to tell which one. You’ll have to reactivate each plugin individually and check your Media Library each time. Once the library stops loading again, the plugin you’ve just activated is the problem. More of this information can be found [here](https://wpengine.com/resources/troubleshooting-wordpress-media-library/).